# IONIC BUILD IOS Does Nothing and just drop to next line

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

When trying to build and run an ionic project, it fail silently (no ouput) without building the project or running the simulator.

> Zeeshans-MBP:my-reddit zeeshansabri11$ ionic build iOS
>
> Zeeshans-MBP:my-reddit zeeshansabri11$ ionic emulate ios

System Details:
Cordova CLI: 5.3.3
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.7
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.3
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.0.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1 Build version 7B91b

Nothing happening. I was getting some errors and check with my Udemy instructor and I have been told that I installed my Node using sudo so I have uninstall complete node, ionic and cordova and then reinstall it now I'm not getting those errors but now Build and Emulate command not doing anything at all.

I have seen similar post on forum but that seems old and recommending downgrade to some really old version not sure if it's still valid.

Btw: I'm new with all Ionic, cordova and node so please go easy on me :)

Comment: same here, used to work in android but when i started to look with IOS , install IOS sim and all that ... everything went doing nothing... X(

Comment: let's just home someone answer to our issue. I have also posted on ionic forum if manage to find a solution will update you. you can keep eye on it too http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-does-nothing-and-just-drop-to-next-line/36067

Comment: there is a bug on node 5, downgrade to node 4 or wait for the fix to be released

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Node 5.0.0
Use Node 4.1.2 instead:

If you installed node via brew, try this:

> brew switch node 4.1.2

It's unbelievable that there is no visible error displayed there.

Comment: on a mac `which node` (combined with checking where that path leads if it's a symlink) and `brew list node` can help check where/how you installed node. also compare the versions of those with the one reported by `ionic info`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update/install following packages:

```
npm install -g ionic cordova ios-deploy
```

It solved the problem on node v7

```
node --version
v7.7.4
```